# Cannot connect to Azure DB with sqlcmd

Tags: sql-server, azure, sqlcmd

I have an Azure Database that I'm able to connect to using [Active Directory Integrated authentication](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48742) and [Sql Server Management Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms) (version 17.1). However, when I try to connect using [sqlcmd](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53591)(version 13.1.811.168), via:

```
sqlcmd -S my-dataabse.database.windows.net  -G -C -Q "SELECT name FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases"
```

I get this error:

> Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server : SQL Server Network Interfaces: Unable to locate the registry entry for adalsql.dll file path. Verify that Active Directory
>   Authentication Library for SQL Server is properly installed. For details, please refer to: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=513072.

If I go to that link, and download the newest version of `adalsql.dll`, it tells me that I already have it installed.  Furthermore, I can confirm that `C:\Windows\System32\adalsql.dll` exists.

Not sure what to try next...

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that the first `sqlcmd.exe` on my search path was the 64 bit version and Sql Server Management Studio only installs the 32 bit version of `adalsql.dll`, so the solution was to add `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn` to the head of my search path so that the 32 bit version of `sqlcmd.exe` would be used when calling `sqlcmd blah blah blah` from the command line.